# Randomly assigning gmail label to every incoming email

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I manage a team that has a shared gmail inbox, is there any build-in way to randomly label every incoming email to "distribute" the emails among the team members?

To be more specific, what I want to achieve is to have 6 labels, say from 1 to 6 and every incoming email would be first assigned label 1, second email would be assigned label 2, etc to 6 and then start over from 1st.

If there's no gmail client-side solution, are there any external add-ons that support this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way but you could create an script by using Google Apps Script or the Gmail API

You could search the [Works with Gmail](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/category/works-with-gmail) category of the G Suite Marketplace for Gmail add-ons.

References

- https://developers.google.com/gmail